# html select drop down box - jquery response

Tags: jquery

```
    <select id="showOption">
        <option id="1">All Friends</option>
        <option id="2">Friends who run</option>
        <option id="3">Friends who don't run</option>
    </select>
```

How can I respond to a user selecting one option or another using jQuery? What is the event, and how does the source look like?

For ex for a button I use (#myButton).click( func()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do something like this:

```
 $('#showOption').change(function()
 {
      var value = this.id;

      // Do Stuff
 });
```

Of course, your HTML isnt entirely great here; you should be relating data on the 'value' attribute, not Id.

Comment: An option is semantically a Text/Value combination. You can provide an ID, but that is the ID of the element, not semantically it's value.

Comment: What's more, purely-numeric IDs are invalid in HTML, cause browsers problems, and are unlikely to be unique if you have multiple select boxes.

Answer (score 3):

The event is called `change()`. [**Manual entry**](http://api.jquery.com/select/).

```
$('#showOption').change(function() {
  //$(this).val() = The value of the select.
});
```